# Modify how results get returned from associated model

Tags: cakephp-2.0

We have a name value pair table with just extra items that can be associated with a property  site_id,  netpark_location_id , etc.

When cakephp returns the hasMany association for the PropertyOption table its in the normal format for an hasMany association:

```
[PropertyOption] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [property_id] => 1
                [name] => prs_company_id
                [value] => 7
                [type] => text
                [created] => 2018-10-02 16:05:38
                [modified] => 2018-10-02 16:05:38
            )
         [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [property_id] => 1
                [name] => prs_channel_id
                [value] => 880
                [type] => text
                [created] => 2018-10-02 16:05:38
                [modified] => 2018-10-02 16:05:38
            )
```

Is there a behavior or afterFind way of massaging the data into

```
 [PropertyOption] => Array
    (
        [prs_channel_id] => 880
        [prs_company_id] => 7
    )
```

Currently I use a function in AppModel that allows me to pass a result set to it but its an extra call

```
public function nameValPair($alias,$results){
    $result = [];
    if(is_array($results[$alias]) && count($results[$alias]) > 0){
        foreach ($results[$alias] AS $r){
            $result[$r['name']] = $r['value'];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Then in the Controller we have to pass the results in

```
$propoption = $this->Property->nameValPair('PropertyOption',$property);
$property['PropertyOption'] = $propoption;
```

Comment: It's not clear to me on reading this what the relation is between the two tables you've shown, where the channel or company IDs are coming from, or even which is the "name value pair table". Without more details (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), I fear you're unlikely to get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: It clearly states which is the Name Value pair table ProperyOption and also lists the columns.   It also says its a hasMany association. I edited to put a flashing sign to make you feel better but the info for someone with Cakephp 2 knowledge would understand "in the normal format for an hasMany association"

Comment: I have plenty of experience with CakePHP. Mostly with the 1 and 3 lines, but still, I know all about hasMany associations. If I'm confused by it, you can be sure that others are too, and this may be why your question has gone so long without any other comments; my suggestion is very much intended to help you to get the help you need. Your edit has clarified things somewhat, but it's still not immediately obvious where the `prs_channel_id` and `prs_company_id` columns are supposed to come from. They're from the name columns in the `PropertyOption` table? Showing that raw sample data could help.

Comment: Sorry we have been crazy busy on another site we are working on ... I updated the sample data to reflect PropertyOptions table now that we have a bunch of data in it

Comment: You can use hash utility in you `nameValPair` function